# Count how many times a string value appears in a column when there are more than one string value

Tags: string, count, powerbi

I am a new to Power BI and I don't know how to obtain a measure which will calculate how many times string 'Poza Targetem' and 'W Targecie' occure in column [IN/OUT].

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU8V4.png)

I would like then, to show the result on pie chart.

I tried to use a function COUNT or COUNTX but it seems that those functions cannot count string values. I also tried to find the solutions in other people question but with no success.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Here is the basis to that: `CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(YourTable), YourTable[columnNmae] = "a string")`. Read up on `CALCULATE` and `FILTER`